# Integrating $f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2 \pi (t-s)s} e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2(t-s)}- \frac{x^2}{2s}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, probability-theory, improper-integrals

I want to integrate the function

$$f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2 \pi (t-s)s} e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2(t-s)}- \frac{x^2}{2s}}$$

on $[0,\infty)^2$ or in other words. I am looking for

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy.$$

Does anybody know if it is possible to do this analytically (thereby I mean not with a computer...I think you know what I mean)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please tell what methods or ideas you have tried yourself so far. Also, I assume that $t>s>0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @mickep yes, well I expanded the exponent and noticed that this is a stupid idea, then I started looking for a substitution in polar coordinates, but did not find a good one. then i thought about symmetries and substitutions but found none. so I cried for help

Comment: Well, you could start by switching the order of integration.

Comment: @Hetebrij don't see where this could lead to.

Comment: do you know the "error-funtion?"

Comment: Well, the integral over $y$ would yield the "error-function".

Comment: yes. and errorfunction $\times$ gaussian can be integrated

Comment: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf you should find here everything u need

Comment: The arctan result below can be found with no computation, noting that the integral is $$\frac{P(X>0,Y>0)}{\sqrt{s(t-s)}}$$ where $(X,Y)$ is gaussian with $$X=\sqrt{s}U\quad Y=\sqrt{s}U-\sqrt{t-s}V$$ and $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard gaussian. Thus, $(X>0,Y>0)$ is the event that $(U,V)$ is in the $(u,v)$-angular sector in the $u>0$ halfplane, bounded by the lines $u=0$ and $v=ku$ for some explicit $k$. By isotropy of the distribution of $(U,V)$, this probability is the angle of the sector divided by $2\pi$, end of proof.

Comment: @Did this nice argument deserves to be an answer ...

Comment: @tired Be my guest--you could write it down as an Appendix to your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with switching the order of integration. Relabeling constants gives:
$$
I=\frac{1}{ab\pi}\int_0^{\infty} dx \left( \int_0^{\infty} dy e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2a}}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2b}}
$$

The inner intgral yields after a subsitution $x-y=q$
$$
I=\frac{1}{2b\sqrt{a\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} dx\text{Erfc}\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{a}}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2b}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi a b}} \underbrace{ \int_0^{\infty} dz\text{Erfc}(cz)e^{-z^2}}_{J}
$$

with $c=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and [the complementary Errorfunction $\text{Erfc}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Differentiating the last integral with respect to $c$ gives a standard integral:

$$
J'= \frac{-2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} dz z e^{-z^2(1+c^2)}= \frac{-2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+c^2}
$$

integrating back is also pleasingly easy
$$
J=\int J'(c)dc= \frac{-2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\arctan(c)+d
$$

now putting everything together

$$
I=-\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{a b}}\arctan\left(-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)+d=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{a b}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)+d
$$

to fix $d$ we may observe that our orinal integral should vanish as $a\rightarrow \infty$ which fixes $d=0$ and therefore:

> $$
> I=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{ a b}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)
> $$